# PHP and ADODB connection fail

Tags: php, server, activex, ado, adodb

I have been tasked to migrate servers. This includes moving over apps I did not build, a couple of which have an ADODB.connection that I cannot seem to fix on the new servers (I only get blank screens).

I have researched quite extensively ADODB.connection with PHP and cannot find a definite source. Most are related to VB Script, or even Excel documents.  I even searched YouTube and the only thing I found wasn't even in English.

I took some of the previous developer's code and created a test.php:

```
<?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);

  // echo 'hello' <-- I can show this to the page
  $Conn = New COM("ADODB.Connection");
  // echo 'hello again' <-- this will not show
  $RS = New COM("ADODB.Recordset");

  $Conn->Provider = "ADsDSOObject";
  $Conn->Properties['User ID'] = "her.something@something.com";
  $Conn->Properties['Password'] = "password";
  $strConn = "Active Directory Provider";
  $Conn->Open($strConn);
?>
```

As you will see in the code above, I obviously can echo 'hello' before the $conn variable.  Nothing works after the $conn variable.

I have no familiarity with ADODB.connection or Active Directory.

How can I test this code if I cannot even echo anything after the $conn variable?  What am I missing?  What can I add?

I do not see anything relating to ADODB in the phpinfo.  The closest is ODBC, which is included.

### Edit

I just added the 2 additional lines as requested by @Hackerman.

Here are the errors the page is displaying:

```
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 25

Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 28

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 226

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 237

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 100

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 180

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 226

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 226

Deprecated: Function mysql_numrows() is deprecated in D:\htdocs\application1\include\database.php on line 237

Fatal error: Class 'COM' not found in D:\htdocs\application1\admin\test.php on line 8
```

The previous developer was indeed using MySQL instead of mysqli or PDO, which explains the deprecated errors.

I'm hoping the last error sheds light on the ADODB problem at hand.

### Edit 2

Installed the php_com_dotnet.dll file into the extension folder and included the file on the php.ini file and got the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `ADODB.Connection': The specified module could not be found. ' in D:\htdocs\application1\admin\test.php:8 Stack trace: #0 D:\htdocs\application1\admin\test.php(8): com->com('ADODB.Connectio...') #1 {main} thrown in D:\htdocs\application1\admin\test.php on line 8
```

Comment: You need to install this in your new serves in order to use ADO https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5793

Comment: Installed.  I restarted the server but I am getting the same result.  Thoughts?

Comment: Can you add these two lines at the begining of your php file `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, try to run the script again and post the results.

Comment: Please go to [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/301202/how-to-check-for-mdac-version) and follow instructions to check that mdac is installed correctly

Comment: @Hackerman - I posted an update.

Comment: Now we are right on track...please update you `php.ini` file as follows https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678325/class-com-not-found

Comment: I made another update.